# AppSync BatchResolver AssumeRole Error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, aws-appsync

I’m trying to use the new DynamoDB BatchResolvers to write to two DynamoDB table in an AppSync resolver (currently using a Lambda function to do this). However, I’m getting the following permission error when looking at the CloudWatch logs:

`“User: arn:aws:sts::111111111111:assumed-role/appsync-datasource-ddb-xxxxxx-TABLE-ONE/APPSYNC_ASSUME_ROLE is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:BatchWriteItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:111111111111:table/TABLE-TWO (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException;`

I’m using `TABLE-ONE` as my data source in my resolver.

I added the `"dynamodb:BatchWriteItem"` and `"dynamodb:BatchGetItem"` to `TABLE-ONE`’s permission:

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:111111111111:table/TABLE-ONE",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:111111111111:table/TABLE-ONE/*",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:111111111111:table/TABLE-TWO",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:111111111111:table/TABLE-TWO/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

I have another resolver that uses the `BatchGetItem` operation and was getting null values in my response - changing the table’s policy access level fixed the null values:
[image]

However, checking the box for `BatchWriteItem` doesn’t seem to solve the issue either adding the permissions to the data source table’s policy.

I also tested my resolver test feature in AppSync, the evaluated request and response are working as intended.

Where else could I set the permissions for a BatchWriteItem operation between two tables? It seems like it's invoking the user's `assumed-role` instead of the table's role - can I 'force' it to use the table's role?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is using the role that you have configured for the table in the AppSync console. Note that that particular role, should have appsync as a trusted entity. [image]

Or if you use the new role tick box when creating the data source in the console, it should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
variable "dynamodb_table" {
  description = "Name of DynamoDB table"
  type        = any
}
# value of var
 dynamodb_table = {
    "dyn-notification-inbox" = {
      type       = "AMAZON_DYNAMODB"
      table = data.aws_dynamodb_table.dyntable
    }
    "dyn-notification-count" = {
      type       = "AMAZON_DYNAMODB"
      table = data.aws_dynamodb_table.dyntable2
    }
  }
locals {
  roles_arns = {
    dynamodb = var.dynamodb_table
    kms      = var.kms_keys
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "invoke_dynamodb_document" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "dynamodb:GetItem",
      "dynamodb:PutItem",
      "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
      "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
      "dynamodb:Query"
    ]
    # dynamic dynamodb table
    # for dynamodb table v.table.arn and v.table.arn/*
    resources = flatten([
      for k, v in local.roles_arns.dynamodb : [
        v.table.arn,
        "${v.table.arn}/*"
      ]
    ])
  }
}

# make policy
resource "aws_iam_policy" "iam_invoke_dynamodb" {
  name   = "policy-${var.name}"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.invoke_dynamodb_document.json
}

# attach role
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "invoke_dynamodb" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.iam_appsync_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.iam_invoke_dynamodb.arn

}
```

Result:

```
resources: [
  'arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxx:table/my-table',
  'arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-2:xxxxxxxx:table/my-table/*'
]
```

Comment: Is that a terraform template?